# How to Get Windows 10 Insider Preview Build Faster?

Tags: windows-10, auto-update

I have turned on the *fast* way of getting insider preview builds. 
However, it is too slow. 
I want the build *14316* or newer.

---

How can you get Windows 10 insider preview builds faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe there is no way to make it faster than the fast ring. There are even faster rings, but they are reserved for Microsoft employees. If you just turned on the mode, wait a little - for me, it was about 20 hours to start to receive the new builds.

If you will not see the new builds in the updates, try to re-enroll. Yesterday, [14328 build released](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14328-for-pc-and-mobile/), so 14316 should be around the corner.